# Is it possible to know root password of Cloud Foundry container on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I guess I might be asking very silly questions, but I am curious if I am able to know a root password of Cloud Foundry container on Bluemix or if I am able to login as a root. Is it possible?

Comment: This question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow as it is not technical and not describing a problem that you are trying to solve. It would be better to post this question on dW Answers (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/index.html). See this URL for info about asking questions on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a user of Cloud Foundry cannot login as root in the application container.  If you're finding a need to do this, ask about that need because there's likely some other way to achieve your task.

An operator of the platform could choose to login to the container as root, but it's rarely necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I talked to someone in operation. She says it is possible but for trouble shoot purpose only.